# how to upload a file using firefoxdriver in selenium testing

Tags: firefox, testing, file-upload, selenium, webdriver

i want to upload a gif file in my application using selenium codes in firefox,
i have the following file input type:

```
<input id="file" type="file" size="27" value="Attach document" onclick="javascript:return     processAttachment();" name="file">
```

i have tried this code:

```
driver.findElementByName("file").sendKeys("E:/plus.GIF");
    driver.findElementByName("file").click();
```

but its is not working, instead a file upload window is opening, can any one help me getting out of it.please

thank you

Comment: The answer is in the html you provided; the onclick event in the element causes some javascript to open the file upload window, and your code is clicking on the element causing the onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

With this line driver.findElementByName("file").click(); you are "trying" to click the field , where you typed the text.It should be driver.findElementByName("NAME OF THE SUBMIT BUTTON").click();